# I would like to know where ideally it is to be sat on an Emirates A380 to get a nice picture of the wing and wingtip as well as the outer landscape?

Tags: airbus-a380, seats

I would like to know where ideally it is to be sat on an Emirates A380 to get a nice picture of the wing and wingtip as well as the outer landscape?

LHR-DXB 7:50 P.M

Comment: The seats in the back. This question does not really seem to be on-topic here though.

Comment: Ideal place to sit would be a **window** seat back of wings

Comment: Sitting in the back means that the landscape below is blurred by the density differences between the hot engine exhaust and the surrounding air. Sit in the upper deck and look for a seat near the leading edge on SeatGuru.com.

Comment: Emirates operates a B777 on that route. Pick a different departure time for an A380. 4:55 or 8:40 pm get you on an A380.

Answer (score 1):

The best seats would probably be in the back because you can see the wing and the ground without having to twist or having the wing in your view.

Here is a picture I took from the back end of a Boeing 757-200. Is it the view that you want?
[image]